# Is there a way to suppress CbsPackageServicingFailure2 logs from Event Viewer

Tags: windows, logging

### overview

Event Viewer reports a large number of events called CbsPackageServicingFailure2.

Is there a way to prevent this log from occurring or resolve the issue it indicates?

However, it is recommended that Windows Error Reporting itself be enabled.

Message on Event Viewer

```
Fault bucket, type 0
Event Name: CbsPackageServicingFailure2
Response: Not available
Cab ID: 0
Problem signature:
P1: 10.0.17763.164
P2: Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Basic-ja-jp-Package
P3: 10.0.17763.1
P4: amd64
P5: unknown
P6: 8024402c
P7: CBS Other
P8: Absent
P9: Absent
P10: FodHelper(LanguageFeaturesOnDemand)
Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER9681.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
These files may be available here:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\Critical_10.0.17763.164_947bf18941b96d6bf9fdbe3df92b4f3fe4ac6c_00000000_84558b46
Analysis symbol:
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 1af51f56-5406-46e3-90f9-b73e801ef6b2
Report Status: 100
Hashed bucket:
Cab Guide: 0
```

### System environment

OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC

Version 10.0.17763 Build 17763

Locale Japan

This PC is a standalone machine and cannot be connected to an external network.

Also, the language pack used by default is English.

This symptom occurs on multiple machines in the same environment.

### Measures I tried

I have tried each countermeasure independently, but it has not suppressed CbsPackageServicingFailure2.

1. Remove Japanese from the language package
2. Change Windows Update automatic update settings
3. Disable WER.

With method 3, Event Viewer no longer reports CbsPackageServicingFailure2, but it also no longer reports any other logs.